# Rails Delete doesn't destroy record, simply refreshes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

My destroy/delete link simply refreshes the post page and doesn't actually delete the record.

```
<span class="delete-button"><%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</span>
```

Controller

```
 def destroy
    @post= Post.find(params[:id])

    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path

  end
```

Comment: Can you log and then tell us the output from `@post.errors.full_messages`? Make sure to look at the errors _after_ you try to destroy it.

Comment: I don't think destroy is being called. The log isn't logging a delete attempt

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use `button_to` instead of `link_to`

That revealed additional error that required me to define the `has_many` association above/before the `has_many :through` associations in the Post model.

Unsure why `link_to` does not work in this case.

Comment: This is a really strange behaviour. I was having the same problem that worked like a charm after I changed to `button_to`.

Answer (score 1):

You are failing to check if `@post.destroy` succeeds, it returns true or false.

Simplest thing to do is to use [`@post.destroy!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy-21) which will throw an exception if it fails. In general, use the ! versions to ensure you don't miss any errors: `create!`, `destroy!`, `save!`, and `update!`.

My guess is the `@post` has associated objects which refer to the Post. These must be deleted before Post is deleted. You can fix this by adding `dependent: :destroy` to its relationships.

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Post does have associated models

Answer (score 1):

If your page is refreshing and not performing a redirect per the controller action, it's possible that the page doesn't have [rails-ujs](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/5699122abf7613465c62f2e50e3af017e95cb609/actionview/app/assets/javascripts) set up. Without it you can't make non-GET requests via hyperlinks, so the link would simply go to the post's `show` page.

If the record is truly failing to delete, it could be due to several reasons. One way to narrow down why the Post failed to delete would be to rescue out of the exception that `destroy!` raises and log or display the post's errors:

```rb
def destroy
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.destroy!

  redirect_to posts_path, notice: "Post deleted successfully"
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed => e
  failure_message = "Post failed to delete: #{e.record.errors.full_messages}"

  Rails.logger.warn "==> #{failure_message}"
  redirect_to posts_path, alert: failure_message
end
```

If you don't have flash messages set up for your view, you can place this in your view file:

```
<% flash.each do |_type, message| %>
  <div><%= message %></div>
<% end %>
```

Now if the post fails to delete you can display a flash message stating why it failed (or you can check your logs for a `==> Post failed to delete: ...` line).

Comment: Not sure why but this does not show any flash message. I get the same result (refresh page)

Comment: It's most likely because you haven't set up your layout to render the flash messages in the view. Can you see what the logs say? You should see a line for `==> Post failed to delete` in your logs somewhere if the post didn't delete.

Comment: The log doesn't mention delete. It only shows the get for building the page.

Comment: I added a snippet for showing flash messages in your view, try adding that to your view file and give it another shot. If the post fails to delete, you should see something rendered in that section of the view.

Comment: Nothing is appearing. I don't think `destroy` is running? The log isn't showing any attempt to delete and there is no flash message. Though my controller and view are exactly like what is above.

Comment: It could be that the `destroy` action is not being hit at all due to the UJS not being loaded for the page (which is what allows you to have delete links). Can you check that your page is loading the rails-ujs library?

Comment: The solution was to use `button_to` instead of `link_to`